# Comma-delimit multiple columns when some values may be null

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to comma-delimit the values contained in multiple columns, when each of the columns could contain a `NULL` value:

```
with

data as (

  select  null a, null b, null c from dual
  union all

  select  'a' a, null b, null c from dual
  union all
  select  null a, 'b' b, null c from dual
  union all
  select  null a, null b, 'c' c from dual

  union all
  select  'a' a, 'b' b, null c from dual
  union all
  select  'a' a, null b, 'c' c from dual

  union all
  select  null a, 'b' b, 'c' c from dual

  union all
  select  'a' a, 'b' b, 'c' c from dual

)

select  a,b,c
        ,case
        when a is not null and b is not null and c is not null then a || ',' || b || ',' ||c
        when a is not null and b is not null then a || ',' || b
        when a is not null and c is not null then a || ',' || c
        when b is not null and c is not null then b || ',' || c
        when a is not null then a
        when b is not null then b
        when c is not null then c
        end abc
from    data
```

Results:

```
A   B   C   ABC

a           a
    b       b
        c   c
a   b       a,b
a       c   a,c
    b   c   b,c
a   b   c   a,b,c
```

Is there an approach that is less cumbersome than what I've done for `abc`, preferably without having to use PL/SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you really want is `concat_ws()`, but Oracle doesn't have one.  But here is an alternative that is a bit less cumbersome than your method:

```
select a, b, c,
       trim(both ',' from replace(replace(a || ',' || b || ',' || c, ',,', ','), ',,', ',')
from data;
```

This creates the string with the commas.  Oracle ignores the `NULL` values in a string concatenation.  It then removes duplicate commas and leading and trailing commas.

Another method is:

```
select a, b, c,
       trim(trailing ',' from
            coalesce(a || ',', '') || coalesce(b || ',', '') || coalesce(c || ',', '') 
           )
from data;
```

I actually like this version better.  It is more generalizable; the intermediate result doesn't have a bunch of comma gumming up the middle of the string.

Comment: change `'c'` to `c` in the first solution

Comment: I'm getting `,b`,`,,c`,`a,,c`,`,b,c` for values `b`,`c`,`a,c`, and `b,c`, respectively for the second option.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @craig . . . I don't see how a comma could appear at the *beginning* of the string in the second option.  But, you could remove both leading and trailing commas.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it by concatenating `,` to column values (a and b) if they are non-null and trimming the trailing `,`.

```
select a, b, c,
trim(trailing ',' from 
     case when a is null then '' else a||',' end ||
     case when b is null then '' else b||',' end || 
     case when c is null then '' else c end) abc  
from data
```

[Working example](http://rextester.com/GZZ94380)

Comment: What SQL dialect has `trim(trailing....)` ? Both you and Gordon used the same syntax. This is not Oracle; in Oracle you use `rtrim()`.

Comment: @mathguy .. look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions based on different versions of TRIM should work, because the comma should not be a "legitimate" character in your data. If it is, you should use a different separator. However, if you do have commas in your data, the TRIM solutions may trim away commas at the beginning or end of your result even if they were part of the data.

You can avoid that by using SUBSTR instead of TRIM. Something like

```
select a, b, c,
       substr(case when a is not null then ',' || a end  ||
              case when b is not null then ',' || b end  ||
              case when c is not null then ',' || c end
             , 2) as abc
from data
;
```

Very similar to vkp's solution, with the comma moved to the front from the back so that the SUBSTR can be written very simply. For any value that is not null, you prepend a comma and then you concatenate the results. Then SUBSTR reads everything except the first character (it starts reading from character number 2), or it returns NULL if the whole concatenation was NULL - exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT  a,b,c
        ,trim(trailing ',' from nvl2(a,a || ',', '') || nvl2(b,b || ',', '') || nvl2(c,c || ',', ''))` abc
FROM    data;
```

** edit **

This works with multi-character (comma space) delimiters:

```
SELECT  a,b,c
        ,rtrim( nvl2(a,a || ', ', '') || nvl2(b,b || ', ', '') || nvl2(c,c || ', ', ''), ', ' ) abc
FROM    data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
select trim(',' from 
    nvl2(A,A || ',', NULL) ||
    nvl2(B,B || ',', NULL) ||
    nvl2(C,C || ',', NULL) ||
from DUAL;
```